# R Shiny Server Gzip Compression

Tags: r, shiny, gzip

Is it possible to enable Gzip compression on Shiny Server (not Shiny Server PRO)? The initial load time on my Shiny app is rather high due to CSS and JS static files and I would like to potentially decrease the load time by enabling Gzip compression on the server.